# Facebook data deletion request error when sending json response

Tags: facebook, laravel-5, facebook-php-sdk

When implementing the Facebook data deletion request, Facebook calls my method from their side and is telling me that the json response im sending back to them is not what they are expecting to receive. If you look at their documentation here [Facebook Data Deletion Request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/create-an-app/app-dashboard/data-deletion-callback/). The response back to Facebook should be as follows

```
{ url: '<url>', confirmation_code: '<code>' }
```

The code Facebook posts in order to return this json is this

```
$data = array(
  'url' => $status_url,
  'confirmation_code' => $confirmation_code
);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Which  does not create what Facebook is intending as a response. There literally needs to be no quotes around the name of the property and single quotes around the actual values. So I built that out using this

```
$return_value = "{ url: '$url', confirmation_code: '$confirmation_code' }";
```

Yes still no success. IM kind of at a loss here since I've been trying various methods with `response()->json()` `json_encode()` when returning either the $data array or $return string I create. That ends up putting double quotes around the entire string or put in escape characters around the url, which is think is one of the reasons why they are telling me the json is not what they are expecting.  So if any one has a clue as to exactly how Facebook wants this response to look like. Please let me know.
Thank you for your help

```
public function removeFBDataCallback(Request $request)
    {
        $signed_request = $request->get('signed_request');
        $data = $this->parse_signed_request($signed_request);
        $fb_user_id = $data['user_id'];

        $fb_user = $this->UsersRepository->CheckFacebookUIDExisted($fb_user_id);
  
        if (!$fb_user) {
  
            error_log("No user with facebook id: $fb_user_id found when trying to remove data during facebook deletion callback");
            return response()->json(['code' => 403, 'data' => ['message' => 'Facebook user not found when deleting facebook data']]);
        }
        else {
            

            $fb_delete_confirmation = new FBDeleteConfirmation();
            $fb_delete_confirmation->facebook_id = $fb_user->facebook_user_id;
            $fb_delete_confirmation->token = genToken(20);
            $fb_delete_confirmation->save();


            $fb_user->is_account_facebook = 0;
            $fb_user->facebook_user_id = null;
            $fb_user->save();

            
            $confirmation_code = base64_encode("abc123");
            $url = url('login').'/facebook'.'/dataDeleteConfirmation'.'?confirmationid'.('=').($confirmation_code);


            error_log('------------------');

            $return_value = "{ url: '$url', confirmation_code: '$confirmation_code' }";
            error_log($return_value);
            return json_encode($return_value);

        }
        
    }
```

Comment: The format their documentation shows is not even valid JSON. I doubt this is really what's expected, much rather they expect valid JSON, and the documentation writers were sloppy. What is the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: Are you sure your script is actually giving the response you think - and not perhaps going into the `if (!$fb_user)` branch?

Comment: @CBroe  I had error messages in my code to make sure the flow is working, so I know it's not hitting the ```if (!fb_user)``` portion  so I know it's completing the request with a 200 response from me. I know that deleting Facebook data and the FBDeleteConfirmation table inserting is working as it should. The issue is Facebook doesn't show any error message on their side. If you look at the bottom of their documentation page it tells you to use the settings->privacy menu and then "send the request" to my server. All it say is "Facebook can't confirm request" but I know its working on my end

Comment: Right now, you appear to be assembling JSON in string form - and then you are encoding that as JSON, again. That can't be right.